# I cannot log in to a website in Android using Jsoup

Tags: android, forms, post, authentication, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to try to log in to [this](https://www.interpals.net/) website. I am using the following code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.interpals.net/")
                                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36")
                                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                                    .followRedirects(true)
                                    .execute();


                            Document doc = res.parse();

                            Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
                            System.out.println("cookies: "+cookies.size());
                            for (String key : cookies.keySet())
                                System.out.println(key);


                            Elements metaTags = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");

                            String csrf_token = "";
                            for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {

                                String content = metaTag.attr("content");
                                String name = metaTag.attr("name");

                                if("csrf-token".equals(name)) {
                                    csrf_token = content;
                                }

                            }


                            System.out.println("csrf_cookieV2 = "+cookies.get("csrf_cookieV2"));



                                res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.interpals.net/")
                                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36")
                                        .data("username", mEmailView.getText().toString())
                                        .data("password", mPasswordView.getText().toString())
                                        .data("csrf_token", csrf_token)
                                        .followRedirects(true)
                                        .cookies(cookies)
                                        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                                        .execute();

                                doc = res.parse();

                            }
```

I have noticed that the log in form has a hidden element which name is `csrf_token`. This value is written in the head HTML but it is added to the form with JavaScript. Jsoup does not support JavaScript so I extracted that value myself from the head and I put it in the `POST` method arguments. What happens is that I cannot log in and every time I am redirected to the log in page. I tried to log in from my browser with JavaScript disabled and if I add the `csrf_token` input field then I am able to log in successfully. I also tried to change some cookies and see if I can replicate the Android behavior on my PC. I was able to replicate it when I changed the value of the `csrf_cookieV2` cookie. The problem is that when I do the `POST` request I send this cookie so the problem should be somewhere else. What am I doing wrong? Any idea?
For the moment, I am able to log in to the website only if I use the WebView in Android.

Comment: @Luk No that would not work. I tried to do that in Chrome and if I do not put the `csrf_token` it does not log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your post url should be https://www.interpals.net/app/auth/login as it is in the action attribute of form tag.

Second this page requires referrer (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

So your second request should look like this:

```
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.interpals.net/app/auth/login")
            .userAgent( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36")
            .referrer("https://www.interpals.net")
            .data("csrf_token", token)
            .data("username", "your-login")
            .data("password", "your-password")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .method(Method.POST).execute();
```

and you will get authorization.

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the cookie parameter to your solution and it worked perfectly!